# Antd Pro - Dynamic routing configuration with a parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd, ant-design-pro, umijs

I have a tricky issue with parameter routing on my antd pro application.

My router configuration is following in `routes.ts`.

```
export default [
...
{
    path: '/board',
    name: 'Board',
    icon: 'DragOutlined',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/board/:id',
        name: 'Board detail',
        icon: 'GroupOutlined',
        hideInMenu: true,
        component: './Board',
      },
    ],
  },
...

{
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/welcome',
},

{ component: './404' },
```

**Problem:**
In the production build, I can't get the page by URL `/board/100` (100 is ID).
When clicking on the link with `/board/100` on `<a>` tag on the page, I see the correct page.

But when putting this URL directly on browser, I got the error `Cannot GET /task-board/100`.

It's very weird. In the development env, everything works correctly, but it doesn't work in the production build.

My antd pro setting in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.1.0",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-card": "^1.19.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-descriptions": "^1.10.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-form": "^1.64.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-layout": "^6.35.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-table": "^2.71.0",
    "@lexical/react": "^0.3.6",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.1.0",
    "@umijs/route-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.19.0",
    ...
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.3",
    "umi": "^3.5.0"
}
```

I have good experience in Antd pro and completed several projects, but can't solve it myself.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Has nothing to do really with `react-router` or `antd`. It's how you are serving the app up wherever you have it hosted. The basic gist is that the server should redirect all page requests to the app's root index.html file so the React app can load and handle routing/navigation internally (*it's a SPA afterall *). Where are you deploying the app? Review the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a feel for what may need to be configured for your specific scenario.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your reply. I hosted on my local server (apache), but for other routes work correctly. I actually have more than 10 routes in the routes.ts. FYI, it's a SPA mode (it's the same as antd pro scaffolding. no customization)  I tried to add .htaccess file on the production build, but no luck. According to my investigation, /board/:id is not recognized in the production build.

Comment: @DrewReese, this also happens when I serve by  `yarn server` (`umi-serve`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Apache server doesn't route the URL for a route with parameter (/board/:id).

So I could solve the problem by adding `.htaccess` file in the production build root folder.

**CRA Deployment guide**

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

**`.htaccess` file should look like the following:**

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

{
path: '/web-c-pass/fairs/add-cpass/:id',
component: './Web-cPass/TableListAddCPassInFair',
},
i hope it will help u

Comment: Please consider adding more information to your answer, so others can better understand and apply it.